# Qt can't connect to any slot manually (UI editor)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am learning to use Qt.

For easier programming I use the UI-Editor.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I want to connect my QTreeWidget, It suddenly doesn't want to do anything.

**I don't want to connect it via UI-Editor, because I (later on) want to implement my own slot, which doesn't get recognized by the compiler** 
*(ERROR MESSAGE: `didnt find slot ... in file ui_mainwindow.h`, although the slot is defined in mainwindow.cpp and declared in mainwindo.h)*

So this is my connection code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    //connects all the objects with the needed slots
     QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::clicked, QApplication::quit);


     ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

***BUT: When I click on any of the items of QTreeWidget, it doesn't quit out of the programm.***

I am absolutely sure it's a QTreeWidget and not a QTreeView, I also use the Linux (-->GNOME) version of Qt 5.7

Also, I don't get any warnings/compiler errors.

Because I am a newb to Qt, I might have overseen a simple error, in this case, sorry :P

Comment: Could you show the declaration/definition of your `quit()` slot?

Comment: the quit slot isn't declared. When I spoke of my own slot, I meant one I want to implement later on... @kefir500

Comment: And your `QTreeWidget` isn't empty, is it?

Comment: nope, I have one coloumn and several items/childs @kefir500

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no `quit()` slot in `QWidget` or its descendant `QMainWindow`.

You should use [`QCoreApplication::quit()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) instead.

---

Below, `qApp` refers to the `QApplication` instance:

**Qt 4** syntax:

```
QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), qApp, SLOT(quit()));
```

**Qt 5** syntax:

```
QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::clicked, QCoreApplication::quit);
```

or

```
QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::clicked, []{ QCoreApplication::quit(); });
```

---

## Update

Found the issue. Check the [`main.cpp`](https://github.com/MaximilianJugendForscht/PhiluminaEngine_Test/blob/master/gameengine/main.cpp) file, you are creating the `QMainWindow` instance instead of `MainWindow`. That is why your derived class constructor isn't even called.

Comment: I have changed the code to '    QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)), qApp, SLOT(quit()));', but it still doesn't work... No compilererrors whatsoever

Comment: change `QApplciation` to `QApplication`

Comment: I have, actually @eyllanesc I also included QApplication

Comment: Use `QObject::connect(ui->treeWidget, &QTreeWidget::clicked, &QMainWindow::close);`

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for pointing out the typo. BTW, why -1? This answer didn't solve the issue, but it indeed does fix one of the initial problems, see the [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42562448/1) of the question.